# Unresolved External Symbols

Tags: c++

I'm working on a small game that requires mouse input (position and left clicks). I have a GameManager class that controls a GameScreen, which includes `d3d9.h d3dx9.h` and `dinput.h`. I had everything working (building, no errors) before I added the mouse input code and `#include <dinput.h>`. However now, I can't build and am faced with

```
1>GameScreen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GUID_SysMouse
1>GameScreen.obj : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _IID_IDirectInput8A
1>dinput8.lib(dilib1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GUID_ZAxis
1>dinput8.lib(dilib1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GUID_YAxis
1>dinput8.lib(dilib1.obj) : error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _GUID_XAxis
```

And aren't sure what caused it. In my Linker I have `d3d9.lib;d3dx9.lib;dinput8.lib;%(AdditionalDependencies)` as Additional Dependencies, and I've made sure all those files are present in the x86 DirectX directory. I can provide additional information if need be, I'm new to C++ so I'm not sure what's typical protocol for sharing relevant information.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en/vcgeneral/thread/f533413d-c700-42b0-80f5-d85ea438f2bf

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try adding the library dxguid.lib (and possibly dinput8.lib) to your linker flags.

Comment: Thank you!! dxguid was the culprit

Comment: Glad to help! If you could close this question by accepting the answer that would be great.

Comment: Had to wait the 15 minutes or so to actually accept your answer ;) thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

go to Project-> properties->Linker-> Input->Additional dependencies and add "dxguid.lib" -> apply. It work for me.